# Deny Skype video access in Linux?

Tags: linux, skype

I have noticed that despite having configured Skype to not access video, during startups it continues to access the webcam momentarily. Skype is not a user, so I am unsure how to modify its permissions. Is there any simple way to truly disable it from accessing video?

Comment: You could enable an apparmor profile to block such access.

Comment: A reasonable suggestion. My impression of apparmor was to expect a learning curve, which is fine, but possibly not simple. I will have a look at a tutorial for it.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: OS = Mint (ubu based). I would prefer to accomplish this without 3rd party software.

Comment: Do you consider apparmor third-party?

Comment: Not to be an obstreperous bastard, but yeah. I like to hone my native penguin power as much as possible. But I don't want to be a pest either.

Comment: Then create a separate user for Skype. Instructions for ArchLinux can be found at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Skype#Use_Skype_with_special_user, but it should also be applicable to Linux Mint (take or give a few tweaks).

Comment: @RobW, looks like an answer.